# How to give different colors to duplicate composition in after effects?

Tags: color

So, I have this composition with an animated letter. Each letter is a different composition. To save me some work I duplicate the repeating letters. However I want to change the colour of one letter all of the repeated letters get the same colour. How can I disconnect in some way the duplicate compositions from the original? Thank you!

P.S. I'm newb

Comment: Are you asking how can you connect all the layers with the same letter together so if you change the color in one they all change?

Comment: I think he's asking how to do the opposite. Clone a layer, but make it have a new source.

Comment: I want the layers to be independent of each other but with the same content.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need to do is:

1. clone the layer,
2. right click and choose **View Layer Source in Project**,
3. duplicate the source in the project window, and finally
4. <kbd>alt/option</kbd>-drag the new source on to the (selected) cloned layer to change its source.

If this is too tedious, I've [written a script](http://blob.pureandapplied.com.au/the-cloninator/) that will clone the layer and create a  unique source for it in one step (it can also recursively clone all the source layers in compositions if need be). There's also a pay-what-you-want script called [true-comp-duplicator](http://aescripts.com/true-comp-duplicator/) on aescripts.com that will do the same job.